# Immutable.js getters for invoking functions in object literal notation

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, enumerable

I'm trying to pass a function into a `Map` in the same way you would using object literal notation.  Is there any way native to Immutable that could invoke the function as though you were using a getter method on an enumerable?

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  format: function() {
    return this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName;
  }
};

person.format(); // 'Smith, John'

var personMap = new Immutable.Map(person);

personMap.get('format'); // function() {return ... // doesn't work
```

Comment: Can you quantify "cleaner"?  I don't think `format` will have the right `this` here either.

Comment: I edited for clarity.

Comment: I just want to say immutable.js does not work in this way. That `this` in the code definitely pointed to somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Immutable.js, but you can always bind the function to the proper `this` before it goes into the collection.

Simplest case:

```
person.format.bind (person);
// create immutable here
```

More generally, if I may presume that the collection is the only way you intend to reference the object and inherited methods are not an issue:

```
function objectAsCollection (object) {
    var key;
    for (key of Object.keys (object)) {
        if (typeof object [key] == "function") {
            object [key] = object [key].bind (object);
       }
    }
    return new Immutable.Map (object);
}
```

This does modify the original object, but in a way that calling `person.format ()` is not affected, and `mapYouMade.get ("format")()` will have `this` pointing at `person`.  Some problems may arise depending on the rest of your code:

- If `person` becomes the prototype of an object or class, the function will always behave as if `this.format` still refers to the prototype instead of the derived object.
- If `person.whateverProperty` is modified, the change is not reflected in the immutable map, but `theMap.get ("format")()` will use the new values since it is bound to the original object, not the entries in the map, meaning that methods in the immutable would be quite mutable.

It sounds like what you want is not actually an immutable map but an immutable object; after all, collections are for homogeneous value types and methods belong on objects to which they pertain.  My advise in this case would be to forget about Immutable.js and use:

```
Object.freeze (person);
```

Which makes the object itself immutable without the hazards inherent to the collection.  If you simply must have a collection for some reason, you must extend the collection class and/or use proxies to get `format` to fetch other entries from its containing collection so that `person` may be mutated independently. Please comment if this is the case, I can show you how to do it, but I am not familiar with Immutable.js classes, and proxies are a complicated beast.